# having error code with error:nil/nil/error

Tags: swift, error-handling

started to learn coding in SWIFT , this error coming up everytime i'm using error methods please help

```
    var context = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
    var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Pattern")
    var results = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error:nil) // Extra argument 'error' in code
    if results != nil {

    }
```

}

```
func createTestPatterns(){
    var context = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
    var pattern = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Pattern", inManagedObjectContext: context) as! Pattern
    pattern.name = "Blue Mushroom"
    context.save(nil) //call can throw but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled
}
```

what should i do here , please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Swift 2.0, they introduced `do/try/catch` for [Error Handling](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html).

Instead of having the error argument, you declare it like this:

```
do {
    try var results = context.executeFetchRequest(request)
} catch let error as NSError {
    // Handle errors
}
```

Same for the `save` method.

```
do {
    try context.save()
} catch let error as NSError {
   // Handle error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

func save() throws

save methods throws exception. Please refer [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObjectContext/save:)

this can be handle as follows

```
do
{
  try context.save()
}
catch let error
{
    print(error)
}
```